# fetch data from hive table into spark and perform join on RDDs

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd, apache-spark-sql

I have two tables in hive/impala. I want to fetch the data from the table into spark as rdds and perform say a join operation.

I do not want to directly pass the join query in my hive context. This is just an example.
I have more use cases that are not possible by a standard HiveQL.
How do I fetch all rows, access the columns and perform transformation.

Suppose I have two rdds:

```
val table1 =  hiveContext.hql("select * from tem1")

val table2 =  hiveContext.hql("select * from tem2")
```

I want to perform a join on the rdds on a column called "account_id"

Ideally I want to do something like this using the rdds using spark shell.

```
select * from tem1 join tem2 on tem1.account_id=tem2.account_id;
```

Answer (score 1):

So we could register table1 and table2 as temporary tables and then do the join on these temporary tables.

```
table1.registerTempTable("t1")
table2.registerTempTable("t2")
table3 = hiveContext.hql("select * from t1 join t2 on t1.account_id=t2.account_id")
```

Comment: Hi holden, thanks, but I already mentioned that I dont want to do it this way.  This is just a simple example.  I have a use case where I have more complex queries.  I want to be able to construct rdd's from a result set and perform join and other operations.

Comment: Ah sorry user1189851, I thought you wanted to avoid doing a join on the original hive tables. In the above code snippet I posted table1 and table2 can be any SchemaRDD (and note that any of the queries we write give us back SchemaRDDs), what did you want table1 and table2 to be? Do you want them to be from non-Spark SQL sources?

Comment: so i have a case where my first rdd is a result set of a query. and second one is a result set of another query.  val rdd1 = hiveContext.hql("select * from table1") and val rdd2. = hiveContext.hql("select * from table2").  I want to perform say join on these two rdds on a common attribute called account_id. The idea is I dont want the join inside the hive context, I should be able to do it using the transformations.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understood the question, but as an alternative you can use the API to join DataFrames, so you can have many things decided programatically (e.g. the `join` function can be passed as parameter to a method that applies a custom transformation).

For your example, it would be like this:

```
val table1 =  hiveContext.sql("select * from tem1")
val table2 =  hiveContext.sql("select * from tem2")
val common_attributes = Seq("account_id")
val joined = table1.join(table2, common_attributes)
```

There are many common transformations available in the DataFrame API: 
http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

table1 and table2 are of type DataFrame. It is possible to transform them into rdd's using:

```
lazy val table1_rdd = table1.rdd
lazy val table2_rdd = table2.rdd
```

This should to the trick. On these rdd's you can use whatever rdd operation.

See also: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-6608 and https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame

Answer (score 0):

You can directly select that column which you want from following code:

```
val table1 =  hiveContext.hql("select account_id from tem1")
val table2 =  hiveContext.hql("select account_id from tem2")
val joinedTable = table1.join(table2)
```